# Fresh re install of debian does not empty trash in gnome

Tags: debian, reinstall, trash

I used to have 2 partitions on my 750 GB disk.

The first one : 200 GB for windows
The second one : 500 GB for debian

Lately, I decided to throw away windows by deleting everything on the 200 GB partition. I have done that while I was logged on debian (mounted the windows partition and deleting everything on it).

After that, I decided to re install debian.

During the first attempt, I choose to spread debian on the entire disk with encryption. But it failed (I supposed it was because encrypting or erasing 750 GB was too much). It failed during the erase process of the entire 750 GB.

So I decided to use only 200 GB. I checked the option that erases everything when in the partitioning steps and set up encryption on it. It went well. But when on gnome, I noticed that there was something in the trash. It was a left over of my last debian (on the 500 GB).

Here is my question : why my trash is not empty ?

thank you for any explanation !

Comment: What happend with the 500 GB partition? Is it still available and readable?

Answer (score 0):

If you had a separate `/home` partition on your previous Debian install the trash will be at `/home/USER/.local/share/trash` and it's contents will not be lost if you upgrade or re-install Debian. In fact, one of the purposes of having a `/home` partition is not losing it's data. Check `/home` to see if there aren't left overs of the previous install as well.